# Sort keys of hash by numerals and dots that like IPv4

Tags: perl, sorting

Suppose my IPvN is a sequence with almost the same format as IPv4, the only difference is that there can be any number of dots or digits. I want to sort a list of such sequences as follows.

- IPv4 is before IPv5, and so on.
- For the same number of decimal points, sorting in ascending order of numbers in the same vertical position from left to right.

```
    8.8.8.8
    20.0.0.0
    1.2.3.4.5
```

---

## Questions

#### 1. How to make it smarter?

I used a crude way to synthesize logical conditional expressions. I know that doing so is quite inefficient and wasteful of memory, especially when there is only a few of abnormally long IPvN, what humans can solve at a glance but I was dragging completely redundant and useless code tails such as `... or $a->[1000] <=> $b->[1000]`.

#### 2. How to implement sorting that meets multiple conditions in a single [**"Schwartzian transform"**](https://wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Schwartzian_transform)?

As you can see below, I made a superimposed Schwartzian transform of double layers.

#### 3. Why did this error occur?

(The first line of my output.)

```
Use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>) at (eval 4) line 1.
```

However, if it is 
`'8.8.8.6.0'   => 6` instead of 
`'8.8.8.8.0'   => 6` in `%IP_counter`, there will be no warning.

I only know that this error is related to 
`'8.8.8.8'     => 3`.

---

### My trash code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use List::Util qw(max);


my %IP_counter =
    (
    '1.1.1.1.1'   => 1,
    '127.0.0.1'   => 2,
    '8.8.8.8'     => 3,
    '20.0.0.1'    => 4,
    '999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999.9'
                  => 5,
    '8.8.8.8.0'   => 6,
    '888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888.8'
                  => 7,
    );


# Find the max length
# Abbr. "c_n_d_m" -> "count numbers divided (max)".
my @c_n_d;
my $c_n_d_m = 0;
foreach (keys %IP_counter) {
    @c_n_d = split /\./, $_;
    $c_n_d_m = @c_n_d if $c_n_d_m < @c_n_d
}


# ?Q1. Question 1 arises here
# Concatenation of hardcode
my @m = (1..$c_n_d_m);

my $cond;
foreach my $i (0..@m-1) {$cond .= '$a->['.$m[$i].'] <=> $b->['.$m[$i].'] or '}
$cond = substr $cond, 0, rindex($cond, ' or ');


# ?Q2. Question 2 arises here
# Sort keys by numeral
# Do a double "Schwartzian transform"
my @sort_by_num =
    # Sort by number of dots:
    map  { $_ }
    sort { (split /\./, $a) <=> (split /\./, $b) }
    map  { [ $_, /(\d+)/g ] -> [@_] }
    # Sort by (regarded as) shift floats:
    map  { $_->[0] }
    sort { eval $cond }
    map  { [ $_, /(\d+)/g ] }
         keys %IP_counter;


# Print the result
my $width = max map {length $_} keys %IP_counter;

foreach my $IP (@sort_by_num) {
    printf "%-*s  =>  $IP_counter{$IP}\n", $width, $IP
}
```

#### Output

```
Use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>) at (eval 4) line 1.
888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888.8  =>  7
999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999.9  =>  5
8.8.8.8                                             =>  3
20.0.0.1                                            =>  4
127.0.0.1                                           =>  2
1.1.1.1.1                                           =>  1
8.8.8.8.0                                           =>  6
```

Comment: Do you really need to represent numbers as big as 1E48? If so then your original question is very misleading, and your values in fact have nothing to do with IP addresses.

Comment: @Borodin Well, I have to admit that the digits won't be that exaggerated :)  So I finally fully re-accepted melpomene's answer.

Comment: So what is a realistic upper limit to the values? The solution is highly dependent on this limit.

Comment: @Borodin Yours are already fully satisfied with the demand~

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I would solve this is by using a Guttman Rosler Transform (GRT). The GRT is a variation of the Schwartzian Transform in which the `sort` block is empty (i.e. standard lexicographic string comparison is used). This is more efficient because `sort` can then run entirely in C code without calling back into Perl code O(n*log n) times (for each comparison). In your case this is even more important because your code invokes `eval` repeatedly, which is slow.

The tricky part of a GRT is how to construct your keys such that

1. they compare correctly, and
2. they allow you to extract the original data afterwards.

[`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) / [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) are often useful here.

Here's how you could apply this to your problem:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @values = qw(
    139.8.0.2
    127.0.0.11
    1.1.1.1.1
    217.0.22.3
    8.8.8.8
    127.0.0.1
    139.12.0.2
);

my @sorted =
    map join('.', unpack 'J>/C'),
    sort
    map pack('J>/C', split /\./),
    @values;

print "$_\n" for @sorted;
```

Output:

```
8.8.8.8
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.11
139.8.0.2
139.12.0.2
217.0.22.3
1.1.1.1.1
```

The idea is to take each string, split it on `.`, then pack the numbers using the format string `J>/C`. This tells `pack` to pack a sequence of chars (octets really) whose codepoints are given as unsigned integers (`C`), but prefix this by a count (`/`) in UV format (`J`), big endian (`>`). `UV` is the C type Perl uses internally for unsigned integers; it's usually 4 bytes (for 32-bit machines) or 8 bytes (for 64-bit machines) wide, and `split` can't produce more fields than what fits in this type.

Thus for e.g. `'139.8.0.2'`, `split` produces `139, 8, 0, 2`, which `pack` turns into `"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x8b\x08\x00\x02"`, i.e. a length value of 4 encoded as a big-endian 8-byte integer (`"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04"`) followed by bytes corresponding to the dotted decimal numbers.

When compared lexicographically, this string sorts according to your criteria:

- The length field is compared first (because it appears first in the string). Big-endian integers sort in ascending numeric order, so strings with fewer numeric components (i.e. fewer dots) are sorted first.
- For strings with identical length fields (i.e. same number of numeric components), the packed contents are compared (each numeric component has been encoded as a byte), which again results in the desired order.

Finally we undo the encoding produced by `split` / `pack` by applying the inverse operations, `join` and `unpack`.

---

That said, a general method to use multiple criteria with the Schwartzian transform is to just produce multiple fields from the first `map`:

```
my @sorted = 
    map $_->[0],
    sort {
        $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] ||
        $a->[2] <=> $b->[2] ||
        $a->[3] <=> $b->[3]
    }
    map [ $_, compute_key_1($_), compute_key_2($_), compute_key_3($_) ],
    @values;
```

Comment: Grateful for so detailed!!! But input `0.0.0.256` will get ERROR `Character in 'C' format wrapped in pack at ...` and WRONG output `0.0.0.0`. **How to deal with numbers of "any" length?**

Comment: @ooo `C` is for octets. If you need to support characters wider than that, use `W` instead (in pack/unpack).

Comment: @ooo That's the maximum integer value on your platform. Your original code won't work right with those values either.

Comment: @ooo I have no idea what you're trying to tell me.

Comment: I mean, is there a way to get around the limit of digits on my machine while still using the GRT to sort?

Comment: @ooo Have you tried getting it to work without the GRT?

Comment: @ooo No, it doesn't. Borodin is also converting the numbers to characters to build a string. Your code doesn't work either; it loses precision when given big numbers.

Comment: I think your method is really nice, but can you help recover (or avoid breaking) the "shape" of the output data? Now compare the outputs - yours: `9.9.9.18446744073709551615` vs Borodin's: `9.9.9.99999999999999999999`. (Both are in the correct order.)

Answer (score 3):

This shows the sorting of the IP addresses and ignores the remaining parts of your code

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my @ips = qw/
    139.8.0.2
    127.0.0.11
    1.1.1.1.1
    217.0.22.3
    8.8.8.8
    127.0.0.1
    139.12.0.2
/;

my @sorted = map { $_->[0] }
sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] or $a->[2] cmp $b->[2] }
map { [ $_, tr/.//, join ('', map chr, /\d+/g) ] } @ips;

say for @sorted;
```

#### output

```
8.8.8.8
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.11
139.8.0.2
139.12.0.2
217.0.22.3
1.1.1.1.1
```

Comment: Does your code intelligently judge on-demand of comparison? That is, for example, will `$a->[1000] <=> $b->[1000]` still be "generated" when it is not needed?

Comment: @ooo there is no `->[1000]`, ever, only 0, 1, and 2. And nothing is "generated".

Comment: @hobbs Even if `1. ...(998 "1")... .1` vs `1. ...(998 "1")... .2`?

Comment: @ooo yes. Look at the code. `->[0]` is the original string, `->[1]` is the number of dots (i.e. the number of elements, minus one), and `->[2]` would be `"\x01\x01\x01`...`\x01"` vs. `"\x01\x01\x01`...`\x02"`.

Comment: Great. When meets many digits, your code sort roughly, output correctly while holding the shape.

Answer (score -2):

Use [`Sort::Naturally`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Naturally) from CPAN. Why reinvent the wheel?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# always use these two
use strict;
use warnings;
# use autodie to automatically die on open errors
use autodie;

use Sort::Naturally;
my %IP_counter =
    (
    '1.1.1.1.1'   => 1,
    '127.0.0.1'   => 2,
    '8.8.8.8'     => 3,
    '20.0.0.1'    => 4,
    '999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999.9'
                  => 5,
    '8.8.8.8.0'   => 6,
    '888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888.8'
                  => 7,
    );

my @sorted_keys = nsort( keys %IP_counter );
print "$_\n" for @sorted_keys;
```

Comment: Hey guy, plz do not ignore the two requirements at the beginning of my post. I've already tried this module before I posted my question and it isn't suitable for my cases at all!

Comment: @ooo It is? Where? BTW, Perl is CPAN and CPAN is Perl. Using one without the other is like using a bicycle without only one wheel.

Comment: Show me your output. Then you'll see it's not sorted in the order I want.